# Saving CKDatabaseSubscription gets “CloudKit access was denied by user settings”

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, cloudkit

I am trying to set up a CloudKit CKDatabaseSubscription and attempting to save it, I get the following error:

'"Not Authenticated" (9/1002); "CloudKit access was denied by user settings"; Retry after 3.0 seconds'

I am able to create records on the private database via the app with no problems, but the subscription will not save.

```
<snip>
       container = CKContainer(identifier: "<valid identifier>")
       publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
       privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase
       createSubscriptions()
</snip>

   func createSubscriptions()
   {
     let sub = CKDatabaseSubscription(subscriptionID: "main")
     let noteInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
     noteInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
     sub.notificationInfo = noteInfo

     let op = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: [sub], subscriptionIDsToDelete: nil)
     op.qualityOfService = .utility
     op.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock = {(subscriptions, name, error) in
                print ("error-\(error)")
            }
     privateDB.add(op)
   }
```

So in the above code, the above error prints from the print in the block. Everything is in scope, compiles fine, user is signed in to iCloud, etc.  Occurs both on simulator and device.

Is an ASPN Certificate needed for CloudKit subscriptions? Or is there some mistake I am making?

Comment: Did you retry after 3 seconds? There are many possible errors that can require you to retry after a short delay.

Comment: Yes.  I added an asyncAfter should the call fail and it reattempts the save.  Subsequent attempts succeed, though not subscriptions show up on the Dashboard, a fetch of subscriptions for the database returns an expected sub, and no notifications are ever received (running on two devices).

Just seems like the initial call should not ALWAYS fail and even though a subsequent one appears to work.

Comment: Well it appears to be definitely specific to CKDatabaseSubscription.  A CKQuerySubscription works just as expected.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error and it went away after I enabled "iCloud Drive" on the iCloud account.